# How to compare web page content using selenium with the help of excel file?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to compare contents in webpage with the actual copy present in the excel sheet(ie.*.xls) with the respective page name..! I tired to do this in java to capture the entire page contents and load it in to the excel sheet next to the actual copy and the compare those cell data,but i ended up with few override problems,please help in this or is there any other idea to do so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am doing somewhat similar as part of my work, just wanted to know few things before posting an answer. Like from where you are getting _actual copy_ of data? What exactly you _tried_ so far? Any code snippets ? Any snapshot for excel file?

Comment: please post what you have tried and where you stuck?

Comment: The actual copy is from the webpage. The script will read the data and write in the excel which will have the expected copy already.[please refer here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qHogs.png)                                                 @ Mitaleek and @dullpointer Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Hi,The code which you are using is really helps to suggest the solution..
As per screen you already have expected values and you are getting actual values from web page. here you need to compare these two. if there is code then we provide better solution.. any how you can try
by collecting the expected values from sheet and compare with collected actual and write the result, may be at the time of writing the actual values..Its may not good but there is another option, just use excel operations to compare two cells if you are placing that file or sheet manually.

Comment: Actually, our approach for copy checking depends on the excel file, where it has entire data, reads and write the values. i would like to know, which approach is better using a excel file, property file,xml,etc.. Are there any different techniques to compare copies?